# Objects with same properties as unic parameter?

Tags: c#, oop

I have two objects with the same properties like this:

```
ObservableCollection<A> FooA
ObservableCollection<B> FooB
```

both model `A` and `B` have a property in common. I've created this method for update the property without create redundancy code:

```
public static void UpdateItemInCollection(A person, ObservableCollection<A> collection)
    {
        foreach (var m in collection)
        {
            m.Name = m.id == person.id;
        }
    }
```

But I can only pass as parameter `FooA`. How can I pass also FooB?

Comment: Make an interface for both classes `A` and `B`

Comment: And btw, `m.Name = m.id == person.id;` would only work if `Name` is a boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an interface or a parent (most likely abstract) class, if that property actually represents the same kind of data in both classes.

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public Person : INamed
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // etc.
}

public People : INamed
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // etc.
}

public static void UpdateItemInCollection(INamed person, ObservableCollection<INamed> collection)
{
    foreach (var m in collection)
    {
        m.Name = m.id == person.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface for both classes:

```
public interface AandB
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then implement it in the classes:

```
public interface AandB
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class A : AandB
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}

class B : AandB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

}
```

Modify your method to get the interface instead of the class:

```
public static void UpdateItemInCollection(AandB person, ObservableCollection<AandB> collection)
{
    foreach (var m in collection)
    {
        m.Name = "whatever";
    }    
}
```

The collections must be the interface type:

```
ObservableCollection<AandB> FooA;
ObservableCollection<AandB> FooB;
```

And finally,you can call the method with both classes:

```
FooA = new ObservableCollection<AandB>();
A objA = new A();
objA.id = "1";
objA.Name = "test";
FooA.Add(objA);
FooB = new ObservableCollection<AandB>();
B objB = new B();
objB.id = "1";
objB.Name = "test";
FooB.Add(objB);
UpdateItemInCollection(objA, FooA);
UpdateItemInCollection(objB, FooB);
```